# Programatically skip configuration method in TestNG

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have a (hopefully) easy question - is there a way how to skip configuration method in a listener?I have a code like this

```
public class SkipLoginMethodListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

    private static final String SKIP_GROUP = "loginMethod";

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod invokedMethod, ITestResult testResult) {
        ITestNGMethod method = invokedMethod.getTestMethod();
        if (method.isAfterMethodConfiguration() || method.isBeforeMethodConfiguration()) {
            for (String group : method.getGroups()) {
                if (group.equals(SKIP_GROUP)) {
                    System.out.println("skipped " + method.getMethodName());
                    throw new SkipException("Configuration of the method " + method.getMethodName() + " skipped");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, this is currently working, however it will also skip all the tests which are supposed to be executed after the skipped `@BeforeMethod(groups = {"loginMethod"})` but I need to skip only the configuration method. So is there a any way how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your listener implement [IConfigurable](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/IConfigurable.html) instead of `IInvokedMethodListener`.

Something like this will skip running the configuration method without changing its status:

```
public class SkipLoginMethodListener implements IConfigurable {
    private static final String SKIP_GROUP = "loginMethod";

    @Override
    public void run(IConfigureCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {
        ITestNGMethod method = testResult.getMethod();
        if (method.isAfterMethodConfiguration() || method.isBeforeMethodConfiguration()) {
            for (String group : method.getGroups()) {
                if (group.equals(SKIP_GROUP)) {
                    System.out.println("skipped " + method.getMethodName());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        callBack.runConfigurationMethod(testResult);
    }
}
```